# data-checklist-model with nested ng-repeat not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat, checklist-model

I am using angularjs and data-checklist-model.But i am not getting the checked value.
Here is my code.

```
<div  ng-repeat='item in categorywisetag'>
              <div class="row text-center" style="margin-top:49px;width:55%;margin:0 auto">
                  <span><large>{{item.name}}</large></span>
                  <div ng-repeat="itemtag in item.tag">
                          <div class="cat-button">
                              <label><input type="checkbox" data-checklist-model="x.item.tag" data-checklist-value="itemtag.id"><span>{{itemtag.name}}</span>
                              </label>
                          </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

And on submit when i try to access the checked boxes:
it gives me undefined:

```
 $scope.createwar = function(){
            console.log($scope.x.item.tag);
     }
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Did you remember to add checklist-modal to your app dependencies?
`var app = angular.module("app", ["checklist-model"]);`

Comment: It seems fine. Maybe you can build a full plunkr or jsfiddle example.